# How to cover branches in unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

I have this function which needs to be unit tested,

I've wrote few specs which is working fine. But in the code-coverage it says `Else path not taken` for this line `if (text !== '') {}`.

I'm not sure how to test variable inside the function.

Below are few specs which I wrote.

```
  it('should split the content correctly', inject([GenerateInlineTagsService], (service: GenerateInlineTagsService) => {
    const obj = service.getView(RANGES);
    expect(JSON.stringify(obj)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(inlineSplitContent));
  }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new test case and pass below value to your function while testing so that `else` branch would be taken:

```
const content = { inlineEntityRanges: [], text: '' }
```

Also, if possible write `else` block of each `if` block as while measuring branch coverage these things are required.

Comment: I didn't get it, already i'm sending the data `const obj = service.getView(RANGES);`

Comment: Yours is a valid test case. However, because of the data you are passing to the function, it always going to execute `if` block. Thankfully, every function could have numerous test cases! Therefore create another test case and pass it such data that `if` block wouldn't get executed.